# REGEX expression: Get the ID after dot or slash + validate other words

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

If possible, I want to pick up the id of the image using a REGEX expression. The ID is a digit that comes after the `/` or after the last dot `.`, like so:

```
gallery/image/89

gallery/image/trip-to-ireland.89
```

But, even if no ID is available, the following should also match the REGEX expression:

gallery/image

gallery/image/

gallery/image/`89`

gallery/image/`89`/

gallery/image/ireland

gallery/image/ireland/

gallery/image/trip-to-ireland.`89`

gallery/image/trip-to-ireland.`89`/

gallery/image/trip-2-to-ireland.`4589`/

Be careful, the following **should NOT** be matched (either because there are many `/` or there is no `.` (therefore it's not really the id))

'--- SHOULD NOT MATCHED ---'

gallery/image//

gallery/image/89//

gallery/image/4m94

gallery/image/94/notok

gallery/image/4m945m6

This is my rule so far, but it doesn't work perfectly...

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/image(?:/[^/]*?([0-9]+))?/?$ gallery/gallery.php?image=$1 [L,QSA]
```

https://regex101.com/r/88azeh/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
^gallery/image(?:/(?:[^/\d]+/?|(?:[^/]*[/.])?(\d+)/?)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/irkwny/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `gallery/image` - a literal string
- `(?:/(?:[^/\d]+/?|(?:[^/]*[/.])?(\d+)/?)?)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `(?:[^/\d]+/?|(?:[^/]*[/.])?(\d+)/?)?` - an optional sequence of:

    - `[^/\d]+/?` - any one or more chars other than `/` and digits and then an optional `/`
    - `|` - or
    - `(?:[^/]*[/.])?` - an optional sequence of zero or more chars other than `/` as many as possible up to the last `/` or `.`
    - `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
    - `/?` - an optional `/` char
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! I just realized that `gallery/image/4m94` and `gallery/image/4m945m6` should also match, but will not return an ID. Im trying to adapt your solution with no success. Any idea how to change the formula so to include those 2. Thanks

Comment: @Marco You need to swap the alternatives and remove `\d` from the negated character class: `^gallery/image(?:/(?:(?:[^/]*[/.])?(\d+)/?|[^/]+/?)?)?$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/irkwny/2).

Comment: Works flawesly! I'm going to study it, adapt it and use this template pretty much on all of my projects! Thank u Master Regex!